# Redshift - multiple BEGIN COMMIT blocks

Tags: transactions, amazon-redshift

I am trying to understand how Redshift interprets one SQL query that has multiple BEGIN and COMMIT.

For ex:

```
BEGIN;
--- sql
COMMIT;
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE table1;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ...
INSERT INTO table1 (select * from table2)
COMMIT;
```

While running multiple queries like this, a few fail with serializable isolation errors.

On the other hand, the below query works fine.

```
BEGIN;
--- sql
LOCK TABLE table1;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ...
INSERT INTO table1 (select * from table2)
COMMIT;
```

Any insight as to what's the issue with the 1st SQL?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to address the issue.  Let me explain.

A serializable isolation error requires 2 sessions (connections to Redshift) to occur. The basic issue is that one session opens a transaction to modify table A based on data in table B, while at the same time the other session tries to modify table B based on table A.  A dependency loop is created so one of these transactions must be aborted.

You write-up indicates that your session is starting a transaction, runs "---sql", closes that transaction, and then start another.  This second transaction is modifying table 1 based on table 2.  This is half of the scenario needed.

What is missing is what is the "other" session doing.  The error message generated will list the 2 transaction ids (xid) that got into a loop.  To understand what is going on you will need to look into what this other transaction is doing and likely why.

I expect that the error is not happening in your second case due to some coherency dependency created in the "--- sql" code that isn't released in this version since there is no COMMIT.  By committing between these sections of code this "other" session is able to start work that enable a loop to be created.

You could just remove the middle "commit - begin" statements and this might fix your problem but it may just make the issue more rare.  Nothing is worse that figuring out a rare issue.  I'd suggest you investigate the "other" session and understand what order of events is really needed and adjust you code to ensure robust operation.

Another clue to what is happening is the use of an explicit LOCK.  This in general should not be needed for proper operation in Redshift.  This statement causes this transaction to wait until all reads of table1 are complete before proceeding and then gaining an exclusive lock.  This makes the risk of a serializable isolation error higher especially if the other session is performing a "LOCK table2;"  You can see how these can create a dependency loop if run at the same time.

When I see explicit locks on Redshift I suspect that was done to work around an issue but generally makes things worse. Redshift uses a MVCC coherency model which is confusing to understand and when explicit locks are introduced many corner cases are created.  Again I think it is best for you to review all the code in flight for these sessions and figure out what should be happening.

Comment: I took a look at the logs and found that one transaction, which was aborted with serializable isolation level on table is doing "delete from tableA where column = filter_value" while the other transaction which was successful was doing "Insert into tableA".  

So to solve this issue, I introduced LOCK tableA as the first statement for these transactions and that fixed the issue

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Now I don't know your full situation but I expect that the issue wouldn't happen if you remove the "middle" COMMIT & BEGIN and remove the LOCK statement.  MVCC is designed to let these types of statements to work at the same time.  The explicit LOCK is adding an additional constraint to the system which is likely adding to the issue.  At the end of the day if you are happy, so am I.

Comment: So unfortunately, removing the "middle" COMMIT & BEGIN did not fix the issue and I had to use the LOCK table to fix the issue. Now with only one BEGIN/COMMIT and LOCK at the beginning of the transaction works fine all the time. The transactions properly wait for other one to finish, only downside is reads would become much slower but I am fine with that. I guess Redshift does not consider INSERT and DELETE on the same table under different transactions to be serializable?

Comment: INSERT and DELETE on the same table under different transactions are serializable in Redshift.  There needs to be another dependency in play for this error.  A dependency loop must be created.  To truly get to the bottom of this you will need to line up the 2 transactions' statements by time and map the dependencies.  Once found you can see how to break the loop.  Or if the lock method is working and robust ...